# Why can I not register a PropertyEditor for String in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.0.3. I've enabled the default `ConversionService` by adding this line to my Spring configuration XML.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I'm also using custom `PropertyEditor`'s for certain data types, so I've registered them for corresponding data types like the following and they work fine.

```
webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new MyPropertyEditor());
```

I have a custom tag library that extends Spring's Form tag library, and I can acess these `PropertyEditor`'s through `getPropertyEditor()` of `AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag`.

What I don't understand is that I can't register a custom `PropertyEditor` for String for some reason. The following wouldn't work.

```
webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new MyPropertyEditor());
```

When I do `getPropertyEditor()`, it always returns a `ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter`, instead of `MyPropertyEditor`.

Is this a bug?

**EDIT**: I realized that I didn't do some stuff right. Spring works just fine.

Comment: Can you supply an answer which details what you did wrong?  You can select it as the correct answer in a couple days, and it might help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code of `PropertyEditorRegistrySupport` (spring 3.0.5), and all it does is:

```
customEditors.put(requiredType, propertyEditor);
```

So in theory it must be working. There is no exception for `String`. Could make sure this behaviour is consistent?